# Prepending and appending set texts to a variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can someone help? I have a column on 30 values that I want to add to another column with text for example:

```
column a  column b 

98675      1(column a value)@google.com    198675@google.com
97875      1(column a value)@google.com    197875@google.com
```

Comment: Use the `CONCATENATE` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try `=A$1&B2&D$1` as in C2 below, and copy down to suit:

[image: SO19690368 example]